# Mac Catalyst app not respecting HomeKit Privacy usage description in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, mac-catalyst, homekit

I'm writing a Mac app using Catalyst, that uses HomeKit to control some accessories.

When running from Xcode there are no issues, it works fine, however when running any other way – directly from Finder, after distributing on TestFlight, or even during App Store Review, the app crashes as soon as it attempts to use HomeKit.

The crash log is very clear, it says:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSHomeKitUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

The problem is that I do have `NSHomeKitUsageDescription` in my Info.plist. It's always been there since I enabled HomeKit.

So far I've tried a bunch of different resolutions:

- I've double and tripled checked the value in the Info.plist, there is a non-empty, reasonable sentence description, against the key `NSHomeKitUsageDescription`, which is shown as "Privacy - HomeKit Usage Description".
- I've switched from an xcodeproj embedded generated Info.plist to a real file-on-disk Info.plist and back again (all worked correctly, except for this).
- I've switched from managed certificates and profiles to manual certificates and profiles and back again (as far as I can tell from research, managed certs should work fine)
- I've checked that the Info.plist in the app bundle does indeed contain the correct key.

So far, no progress, it just always crashes with the same result. Annoyingly because the crash error message is so obvious all the search results I've found here, on Google, or on the Apple dev forums are saying "just add the key", which I've done with no success.

---

One potentially complicating factors that could be involved, my app contains an embedded macOS-only framework that it uses to access AppKit. I used the technique from an open-source app that apparently successfully uses HomeKit, so I don't expect that to be causing the issue. I've also tried adding the key to the framework's info.plist as well but to no effect. Disabling the framework doesn't help either. I can add more detail about this if necessary, but I don't think it's the cause of the issue.

---

Updates to clarify things:

- Already accounting for the bug in Xcode 14 that misses HomeKit entitlements.
- Reproducible on macOS Ventura and on Xcode Server with Monterey.
- Tried re-signing the framework after embedding in the app.

Comment: I've also checked that Gui Rambo's HomeKit signing solution for the Xcode 14 beta doesn't apply here, or if it does, it's insufficient to solve the issue. https://gist.github.com/insidegui/1275b0e81bb7b5a525368d55ecc96e2c

Comment: Oh, also, I'm not translating the app yet so there's no issue with an InfoPlist.strings.

Comment: This is also reproducible with both Xcode 14.0.1 and the Xcode 14.1 beta.

Comment: Have you the HomeKit entitlement ?

Comment: Yes, and that script mentioned above ensures that the entitlement is definitely being added, as there is a bug in Xcode 14 that strips it out.

Comment: Was it running in xCode 13.4.1 ?

Comment: No, as mentioned, it's in Xcode 14. I've had this issue on 14.0.1 and the 14.1 beta.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709819) : it seems that xCode 14 suppress the entitlement.

Comment: Again, please read the question and the comments above – this is a known issue that I'm already working around. It's also a different issue to the one I am having, and it exhibits in a different way.